# Combination problem of choosing sauces for different people

Tags: combinatorics

Alex is planning to host a barbecue party at the park, serving himself, Bailey, Charlie, and Dana. Alex wants to purchase a bottle of sauce for each person. At the grocery store, there are a total of 30 different sauces available. Each type of sauce (A, B, C, D, E) is offered by 6 different brands. It is possible for multiple people to choose the same type and brand of sauce. Bailey and Charlie will only accept sauce of type A or B. Dana can accept any type of sauce except sauce E. Additionally, among the 4 selected sauces, at least one of them must be of type C. How many different ways can Alex select the 4 sauces?

My attempt is:
Consider the situation where there is no restriction that one of them must choose type C:
C(12+1-1, 1)*C(12+1-1,1)*C(24+1-1,1)*C(30+1-1,1)
=103680
The situation that none of them choose type C:
C(12,1)*C(12,1)*C(18,1)*C(24,1)
=62208
Ans is:
103680-62208
=41472
Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  For instance, typing `$\binom{n}{k}$` produces $\binom{n}{k}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is correct.  Below, I have rephrased your argument in words rather than formulas.

Since Bailey and Charlie will only consider sauces A and B, each of which is sold by six brands, they each have $2 \cdot 6 = 12$ choices.  Since Dana will consider any type of sauce except $E$, Dana has $4 \cdot 6 = 24$ choices.  Alex has $5 \cdot 6 = 30$ choices.  However, we require that somebody chooses sauce C.  Since neither Bailey nor Charlie will consider sauce C, that person must be Alex or Dana.  Therefore, we must subtract those cases in which neither Alex nor Dana chooses sauce C.

If Alex does not choose sauce C, Alex is left with $4 \cdot 6 = 24$ choices; if Dana does not choose sauce C, Dana is left with $3 \cdot 6 = 18$ choices.  Since the number of choices for Bailey and Charlie is not affected by the requirement that some person must choose sauce C, they still each have $12$ choices.

Thus, the number of admissible sauce selections is
$$30 \cdot 12 \cdot 12 \cdot 24 - 24 \cdot 12 \cdot 12 \cdot 18 = 41,472$$